# Python: Count element in a list and putting the result in tuples

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list

```
["Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma", "Beta", "Alpha"]
```

I need to count the repetion of elements in this list and to put the result in a list of tuples in descending order.

If the count of two of the elements is the same, I need to sort them in reverse alphabetical order (Z->A)

This is the expected output

```
[('Beta', 2), ('Alfa', 1), ('Alpha', 1), ('Gamma', 1)]
```

My idea is to start splitting the string as following

```
def count_items(string):
    wordlist = string.split(' ')
```

But I have no idea of how to continue.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` built module along `most_common` method

```
 from collections import Counter

 >>> l = ["Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma", "Beta", "Alpha"]
 >>> Counter(l).most_common()
 >>> [('Beta', 2), ('Alfa', 1), ('Alpha', 1), ('Gamma', 1)]
```